# NodeJs to Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I need to use nodejs library in my angular project but got example code in nodejs. I have installed library through npm command and import to my component. But it always show undefined.

```
npm install phenix-edge-auth --save

const TokenBuilder = require('phenix-edge-auth');

// Create a token to access a channel
const token = new TokenBuilder()
    .withApplicationId('my-application-id')
    .withSecret('my-secret')
    .expiresInSeconds(3600)
    .forChannel('us-northeast#my-application-id#my-channel.1345')
    .build();
```

How to use this code with angular app?

Comment: please show us the error.

Answer (score 0):

Import it as angular way..

```
import * as TokenBuilder from 'phenix-edge-auth'
```

Comment: For accuracy's sake, it's the ES6 method of importing - not the CommonJS method, Angular uses ES6.

Comment: I have already importing same as mentioned above but when i tried to get token but TokenBuilder alwayes shows undefined for const token = new TokenBuilder() line.

Comment: It also shows this error message: ``` core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: crypto.createHmac is not a function ```